# dart null safety and typing issues

Tags: dart, udp, dart-null-safety, uint8list

I'm trying to learn Dart, but I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around the Null Safety. I have the function below, which I copied straight from the dev example (https://pub.dev/packages/udp) and tweaked for my code just slightly.

```
void udpConnection(port) async {
    var sender = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.any(port: Port(65000)));
    
    var dataLength = await sender.send('Hello World!'.codeUnits, Endpoint.broadcast(port: Port(port)));
    
    var receiver = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.loopback(port: Port(65002)));
    try {
        receiver.asStream(timeout: Duration(seconds: 20)).listen((datagram) {
            String s = new String.fromCharCodes(datagram.data);
            print(s);
        });
    } catch(e) {
        print(e);
    }
    
    // close the UDP instances and their sockets.
    sender.close();
    receiver.close();
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Property 'data' cannot be accessed on 'Datagram?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'Datagram' is from 'dart:io'.
Try accessing using ?. instead.
                                        String s = new String.fromCharCodes(datagram.data);
                                                                                     ^^^^
```

However, if I do `String s = new String.fromCharCodes(datagram?.data);`, I get the following error:

```
Error: The argument type 'Uint8List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<int>' because 'Uint8List?' is nullable and 'Iterable<int>' isn't.
 - 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
                                String s = new String.fromCharCodes(datagram?.data);
                                                                    ^
```

How can I access the data property of the Datagram correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *conditional member access* operator (`?.`) evaluates to `null` if the left-hand-side is `null`.  The point of it is to avoid generating a null-pointer exception by attempting to access a non-existent member on `null`.

Using `String.fromCharCodes(datagram?.data)` would not magically avoid calling the `String.fromCharCodes` constructor, and `String.fromCharCodes` expects a non-null argument.

You either must give `String.fromCharCodes` a value that you guarantee is not `null` or must avoid calling it.  Examples:

```dart
// If datagram?.data is null, fall back to using an empty string.
var s = String.fromCharCodes(datagram?.data ?? '');
```

or:

```dart
var data = datagram?.data;
if (data != null) {
  var s = String.fromCharCodes(data);
  ...
}
```

I strongly recommend reading [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) if you haven't already done so.

Note that `?.` and `??` are *null-aware* operators but aren't really about null-safety.  Null-safety is about using the type system to ensure that variables cannot be `null` when you don't expect them to be.

Comment: I have read the docs concering Dart's null safety, however the operators confused me. Using `var data = datagram?.data; if(data != null) { var str = String.fromCharCodes(data); stdout.write(str); }` yields no result. Is it safe to assume, then, that there is no response from the remote server?

Comment: @chaoskreator That would imply that `datagram` is `null`.  I am not familiar with `package:udp` and don't know in what circumstances it would be `null`.